# How can I find the max value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, max

Hi its my first time using python

I have a dictionary:

```
players= {"Gehrig":{"atBats":8061, "hits":2721},
 "Ruth":{"atBats":8399, "hits":2873},
 "Williams":{"atBats":7706, "hits":2654}}
```

I want to find the most hits by any of the three players.

Desired output:

```
The most hits by one of the
players was 2873.
```

My input:

```
max(players.hits())
maximum = max(players,key=players.get)
max(players,key=players.get)
```

But I am only getting errors such as:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a list comprehension or generator expression to traverse only the number of hits:

```
players= {"Gehrig":{"atBats":8061, "hits":2721},
 "Ruth":{"atBats":8399, "hits":2873},
 "Williams":{"atBats":7706, "hits":2654}}

max(player["hits"] for player in players.values())
# 2873
```

If you want to see which player had the most hits:

```
max(players.keys(), key=lambda p: players[p]["hits"])
# 'Ruth'
```

Comment: Hi Tom, im new to python can you please explain the syntax in "players.values())."

Comment: @lilzuzu It simply returns all of the values in a dictionary. For example, `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}.values()` would be `[1, 2, 3]`.